# Disable input field inside ul

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

How can we disable input field inside an ul element on page load.

```
<ul aria-labelledby="prefix-number" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width:80px; overflow-y: scroll;  max-height: 10em;">
<c:forEach var="cso" items="${dl.cso}" varStatus="cart">
<input type="hidden" class="input-field" name="pos_${name}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: you can't really disable a hidden input, hidden inputs are just used for storing data they do not interact with the user.  See my answer , I think you were looking for a textbox .  Otherwise it does not make sense that you want to disable a hidden input

Answer (score 1):

```
<input disabled="disabled"  class="input-field" name="pos_${name}"/>
```

first or all I don't think you want a input of `type="hidden"`you are probably looking for a textbox which is disabled.

the attribute `disabled` will do that

to enable , something like this:

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click' , '.radioClass' , function(e){
       $('.dropdown-menu').find('input').prop('enabled' , true);
   });
});
```

Comment: I wanted to achieve on page load and enable the same on click of radio button

Comment: this will achieve that on page load, you are going to need javascript to change the input to enable it on the radio click

Comment: this answered your question "How can we disable input field inside an ul element on page load."

Comment: how shall i enable it on click of radio button

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do it by html code or from jquery. 

From Html :
You just need to append "disabled" in your input tag.
When you applied disabled in any tag then user can not change any thing in that tag.
Also you can put "disabled" any where in tag like

```
<input type="hidden" class="input-field" name="pos_${name}" disabled/>
```

or

```
<input disabled type="hidden" class="input-field" name="pos_${name}"/>
```

From JQuery :

you just need to add 1 line to set disable is true or false:

for disable any tag :

```
$("#inputId").prop('disabled', true);
```

for enable any tag :

```
$("#inputId").prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<input type="hidden" class="input-field" name="pos_${name}" disabled/>
```

for doing it dynamically you can use this like...

Use this on page load to disable  input box

```
 $(".input-field").prop('disabled', true);
```

And use this for enabling input box on particular event

```
$(".input-field").prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: I wanted to achieve on page load and enable the same on click of radio button

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery

```
<input type="hidden" id="inputId" class="input-field" name="pos_${name}"/>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#inputId").prop('disabled', true);
});
```